# Generic Stack implementation in haskell

Tags: haskell, stack

I am trying to create a generic implementations of stack operations. On compiling it gives an error:

```
Duplicate instance declarations:
      instance Show a => Show (Stack a) -- Defined at stackOp.hs:2:29
      instance Show a => Show (Stack a) -- Defined at stackOp.hs:11:10
```

Here is my code:

```
data Stack a = Stack [a]
               deriving (Eq,Show,Ord)

printelems :: (Show a) => [a] -> String
printelems [] = ""
printelems x = show x
printelems (x:xs) = show x ++ "->" ++ (printelems xs)



instance (Show a) => Show (Stack a)
 where
 show (Stack l) = printelems l

empty :: Stack a
empty = []

push :: a -> Stack a -> Stack a
push x s = x:s
```

Comment: Don't derive `Show` (remove `deriving Show`) if you define your own `Show` instance.

Comment: @StéphaneLaurent - If I do so it give me errors like         "stackOp.hs:16:9:
    Couldn't match expected type `Stack a' with actual type `[a0]'
    In the expression: []
    In an equation for `empty': empty = []

stackOp.hs:19:12:
    Couldn't match expected type `Stack a' with actual type `[a]'
    In the expression: x : s
    In an equation for `push': push x s = x : s

stackOp.hs:19:14:
    Couldn't match expected type `[a]' with actual type `Stack a'
    In the second argument of `(:)', namely `s'
    In the expression: x : s
    In an equation for `push': push x s = x : s

Comment: This is another error... Let me take a look but perhaps we need an expert here (I'm not one).

Comment: @StéphaneLaurent Okay. Thanks for the help you did here.

Comment: There are at least three errors... I still look

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is your code with three corrections:

```
-- do not derive Show since you define it
data Stack a = Stack [a]
               deriving (Eq,Ord)

-- there was a redundant pattern matching here
printelems :: (Show a) => [a] -> String
printelems []     = ""
printelems (x:xs) = if null xs then show x else show x ++ "->" ++ printelems xs

instance (Show a) => Show (Stack a)
 where
 show (Stack l) = printelems l

-- "Stack" was missing
empty :: Stack a
empty = Stack []

-- "Stack" was missing
push :: a -> Stack a -> Stack a
push x (Stack s) = Stack (x:s)
```

Comment: Note that I have not tested anything... I only guarantee the code compiles now.

Comment: Thank you very much. Now it is getting compiled. I think you are an expert.

Comment: You're welcome @SushodhanVaishampayan. You could upvote the answer and click the checkmark if you're satisfied. And no I'm not an expert. Most of the Haskell questions asked on Stackoverflow and their answers are the cosmos for me ^^